# Prevent saving a specific key with Vuex-persist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I just wanted to know if there was a way to prevent saving a specific key from my Vuex state with Vuex-persist?

I saw on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist/issues/99) how to only save some specific keys, but what I would like is the opposite.

For example, I'm trying to code a basic chat app with Vue.js, and I would like to store some chat and authentication data. But I have an "error" key in my state which is handling the display of some error messages if there is any error (invalid authentication, invalid message...). Let's say that an user tried to login to the app but forgot his correct password, tried several times and then closed the tab; decided to reopen it later after he remembered his correct password: the app shouldn't display again the last error message about his incorrect password...

Thank you very much for your help in advance! :)